# Declare a Julia function that returns a function with a specific signature

Tags: function, types, julia

How can I declare a Julia function that returns a function with a specific signature. For example, say I want to return a function that takes an Int and returns an Int:

```
function buildfunc()::?????
   mult(x::Int) = x * 2
   return mult
end
```

What should the question marks be replaced with?

Comment: Julia does not have a syntax for declaring precisely the signature of a method returned by a function method.

See the discussion [Function Parameter Speculation](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/17168) for more thoughts.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Function` type for this purpose. From Julia documentation:

> Function is the abstract type of all functions

```
function b(c::Int64)::Int64
        return c+2;
    end

function a()::Function
        return b;        
    end
```

Which prints:

```
julia> println(a()(2));
```

> 4

Julia will throw exception for Float64 input.

```
   julia> println(a()(2.0));
```

> `ERROR: MethodError: no method matching b(::Float64)`    `Closest candidates are: b(::Int64)`

Comment: Fair enough, how do you specify that the function you are returning takes an int and returns an int

Comment: This is not possible as far as I know.
There is the abstract type "Function" and each function is a concrete subtype of it. There is no intermediate type with specified argument types (this would btw. only make sense for methods, not functions, in Julia).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Other languages such as C allow to declare the signature of the function returned by a function and I assume there is a legitimate reason for it. Even if the purpose is solely for asserting (and I assume there might be other good reasons), then why not?

Answer (score 3):

One thing needs to be made clear.
Adding a type declaration on the returned parameter is just an assertion, not part of function definition. To understand what is going on look at the lowered (this is a pre-compilation stage) code of a function:

```
julia> f(a::Int)::Int = 2a
f (generic function with 1 method)

julia> @code_lowered f(5)
CodeInfo(
1 ─ %1 = Main.Int
│   %2 = 2 * a
│   %3 = Base.convert(%1, %2)
│   %4 = Core.typeassert(%3, %1)
└──      return %4
)
```

In this case since the returned type is obvious this assertion will be actually removed during the compilation process (try `@code_native f(5)` to see yourself).

If you want for some reason to generate functions I recommend to use the `@generated` macro. Be warned: meta-programming is usually an overkill for solving any Julia related problem.

```
@generated function f2(x)
    if x <: Int
        quote
            2x
        end
    else
        quote
            10x
        end
    end
end
```

Now we have a function `f2` where the source code of `f2` is going to depend on the parameter type:

```
julia> f2(3)
6

julia> f2(3.)
30.0
```

Note that this function generation is actually happening during the compile time:

```
julia> @code_lowered f2(2)
CodeInfo(
    @ REPL[34]:1 within `f2'
   ┌ @ REPL[34]:4 within `macro expansion'
1 ─│ %1 = 2 * x
└──│      return %1
   └
)
```

Hope that clears things out.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Other languages such as C allow to declare the signature of the function returned by a function and I assume there is a legitimate reason for it. Even if the purpose is solely for asserting (and I assume there might be other good reasons), then why not?

Comment: Because in 99% of all cases you return functions, not method objects. And it's awefully hard to give types to functions in a multi-dispatch language. But see, e.g., this issue: https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/33784.